# Return value of dynamically determined cell

Tags: vba, excel

The code below verifies if column A in "Sheet1" has the same value as column A in "Sheet2". If so, an email address should be taken from column B "Sheet2".

My problem is getting the email address from "Sheet2" column B.

```
Sub mail()

    Dim A As Long
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim check

    Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
    Set sh1 = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Set sh2 = wb.Worksheets(2)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For A = 2 To sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        check = Application.match(sh1.Cells(A, 1).Value, sh2.Columns(1), 0)

        If IsError(check) Then
            MsgBox "No email was found!"
        Else
            ' i am not able to set this.
            'h = take the email address from sheet2 column B

            Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set OutMail = OutApp.createItem(olmailitem)
            Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
            ActiveWorkbook.Save

            With OutMail
                .Display
                .To = h ' attached the email address
                .cc = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "Test - " '& B & " " & F
                .htmlbody = "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:15'>" & "Hi " & C & "<BR/>" & "<BR/>" & "Please check the attached template." & "<br/>" & "<BR/>" & "Change data if required." & "<BR/>" & "<br/>" & "This e-mail has been automatically send! " & "<br/>" & "<br/>" & "With best regards," & "<br/>" & "<br/>" 
                .attachments.Add wb2.FullName
            End With

            ActiveWorkbook.Close              
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: ① `Workbooks(test).Worksheets("Sheet1")` doesn't make much sense instead use `Set test = Worksheets("Sheet1")` and then you can use it eg like `test.Range("A2")…` ② you don't need to select and activate ③ Don't use `On Error Resume Next` it makes you just blind for any errors, but they still occur. You just don't see them. Use a proper error handling instead. Remove it (both!) and tell in your question which errors you get and where. ④ And it may be a good idea to clean up your code and use proper indentation. This is essential to understand and read code easily, especially for beginners.

Comment: I didn't get any errors on the code below. Yes, I will try to take into consideration your advice and give it another interpretation. Thanks! :)

Comment: Of course you didn't get any errors, because of `On Error Resume Next` you cannot see them! ⑤ you might also consider using meaningful variable names instead of `A, G, h, i` which makes it **much** easier to understand. E.g Using `i` as a range is very unusual because almost everyone uses `i` as a counter. Eg instead of `h` name it `EmailAddress` this is something you easily understand while reading the code while `h` is very meaningless.

Comment: just added my second interpretation. Thanks

Comment: hm your code still leaves some questions: You `Set sh1` but then use `sh1Rec` which is not declared as a variable. Make sure you use `Option Explicit` and you declare **every** variable properly. Without `Option Explicit` you won't see any variable missnamings like that. • Also you still use `On Error Resume Next`. • And `h = sh2 .Cells(A, 2).Value` would eg. read row A column 2. • And I really suggest again to indent your code properly which is necessary to understand the logical structure of your code more easily.

Comment: Yes, was my mistake as I just copied the code for the mail part without realizing the "error resume.." part. I have declared the variables correctly now. The logic for me seems pretty straight now, at least as I am reading the code, but as I said, I am not able to set the "Else". I guess a loop should be used in order to verify column A and B from sheet 2? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167714/discussion-between-p-and-alex2002).

Answer (score 2):

With the help of "PEH" i succeed in finding a solution for this:

```
Sub mail()

    Dim A As Long
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Dim check

    Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
    Set sh1 = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Set sh2 = wb.Worksheets(2)

    For A = 2 To sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        check = Application.match(sh1.Cells(A, 1).Value, sh2.Columns(1), 0)

        If IsError(check) And Not IsEmpty(sh1.Cells(A, 1)) Then
            MsgBox "No email was found!"
        Else
            h = sh2.Cells(check, 2).Value


            Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set OutMail = OutApp.createItem(olmailitem)
            Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
            wb.Save

            With OutMail
                .Display
                .To = h
                .cc = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "Test - " '& B & " " & F
                .htmlbody = "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:15'>" & "Hi " & C & "<BR/>" & "<BR/>" & "Please check the attached template." & "<br/>" & "<BR/>" & "Change data if required." & "<BR/>" & "<br/>" & "This e-mail has been automatically send! " & "<br/>" & "<br/>" & "With best regards," & "<br/>" & "<br/>"
                .attachments.Add wb2.FullName
            End With

            wb.Close
        End If
Next

End Sub
```